# ValidatorCalloutExtender and ModalPopupExtender Issues on MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have just created a website with a MasterPage. I have two conditions that will illustrate my problem:

**Condition 1:**

I have added a **ModalPopupExtender** on website.master. It has three fields and each field has a **RequiredFieldValidator** and a **ValidatorCalloutExtender**.

**Condition 2:**

I have a few different pages where you can click on a registration link. When you click the registration link, a registration form will appear. This form also has **RequiredFieldValidators** and **ValidatorCalloutExtenders** for each field.

**Problem:**

If I open a registration form and want to place my feedback, I click on the feedback button. The feedback modal popup displays. If I click on the submit button without filling the feedback form, it should give me the error in **ValidatorCalloutExtender** format on the **ModalPopupExtender** panel. However, it doesnt show me any error but the **ValidatorCalloutExtender** does show on the registation form along with respective validation.

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender CancelControlID="lnk_cancel" ID="popup_change_password" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
    runat="server" TargetControlID="ImageButton1" PopupControlID="panel_change_password">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="panel_change_password" runat="server" Style="display: none; height: 400px;
    width: 400px; padding-left:30px; background-repeat:no-repeat;" BackImageUrl="~/Images/background.gif">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
     <tr>
            <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400px">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="lnk_cancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/close.gif" Height="30px"
                                Width="30px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_new_password" runat="server" Text="Your feedback is important to us."
                    CssClass="login_font1"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_name" runat="server" Text="Name" CssClass="Label_Styles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;:&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox_Styles"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_email" runat="server" Text="Email Address" CssClass="Label_Styles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;:&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_email" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox_Styles"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_comment" runat="server" Text="Comments" CssClass="Label_Styles"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;:&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_comment" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox_Styles" Height="120px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the above code in an `UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and `ChildrenAsTriggers="False".`
So it will look something like :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="sbsModalExtenderUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
    Visible="False" ChildrenAsTriggers="False">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="StepByStepBookingPanel" runat="server" Enabled="false" EnableViewState="false"
            Style="display: block" CssClass="mediumModalPopup" ScrollBars="Auto" Width="800px"
            Height="300px" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
            <div id="clientCoordDiv" runat="server">
                <table id="StepByStepTable" runat="server">
```

etc...

```
                </table>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeStepByStepBooking" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
            PopupControlID="StepByStepBookingPanel" CancelControlID="BtnCancel" OnCancelScript="ClearStepByStepPopup"
            TargetControlID="hdnStepByStepButton" DropShadow="true" BehaviorID="modalwithinput" />
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="ClientCoordinatorCompareValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select a Client Coordinator"
            ControlToValidate="ddlClientCoordinator" Display="None" Operator="NotEqual" SetFocusOnError="True"
            Type="Integer" ValueToCompare="0" ValidationGroup="SelectionRequired">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CVOCoordinatorCompareValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select a CVO Coordinator"
            ControlToValidate="ddlCVOCoordinator" Display="None" Operator="NotEqual" ValueToCompare="0"
            Type="Integer" SetFocusOnError="True" ValidationGroup="SelectionRequired">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="CompareClientCoordinatorExt" runat="server" Enabled="True"
            TargetControlID="ClientCoordinatorCompareValidator" BehaviorID="ClientValidatorExt">
        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
        <ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="CVOCoordinatorCompareValidatorExt" BehaviorID="CVOValidatorExt"
            runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="CVOCoordinatorCompareValidator">
        </ajax:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will keep the dialog up while you validate it. Unfortunately, I do not have the full solution since my validator messages are not displaying. So far, from what I am getting on the Net it is a problem with the Ajax library. Ugly!
Oh well, hope this helps someone...